# Salesforce FieldService - Define template for subject of auto-generated WorkOrders

Tags: field-service-lightning, work-order

In *Salesforce FieldService*, I recently migrated my `MaintenancePlans` from using frequency fields (FF) (*frequency* and *frequency type*) to using `MaintenanceWorkRules` for auto-generating my maintenance `WorkOrders` due to the upcoming [Maintenance Plan Frequency Fields Retirement](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000393359&type=1).

The generation of `WorkOrders` works fine, but I have an issue with the *subject* of the auto-generated `WorkOrder`.

For an `Asset` "*My Test-Asset*" requiring a maintenance visit on *18th of October 2023*, the two methods with frequency fields (FF) and `MaintenanceWorkRules` (MWR) have different results for the subject of the auto-generated `WorkOrder`:

- FF:  "*Maintenance My Test-Asset: 18th October 2023*" (desired)
- MWR: "*Maintenance: 18th October 2023*" (insufficient)

(subjects translated from german, might not be exact outcome in english).

To differentiate between the `WorkOrders`, I desire the FF-method outcome.
However I cannot find where either method is defining the *subject* template. Is it a *FieldService* internal / hidden functionality which cannot be edited, and if yes why does generation from `MaintenanceWorkRules` use a different template? Or can I explicitly define the subject template?

Note:

- The Maintenance plan definitely has an `Asset` linked (as `MaintenanceAsset`), so
  information should be available for a potential template using the `Asset` name as input
- I know I could re-define the *subject* with a flow on `WorkOrder` creation, but somewhere the *subject* template must have been defined and I would like to change it there instead of overruling this template in a custom flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to Salesforce Support as well and got this response.

> After discussing the issue with our internal team and conducting a small Proof of Concept (POC) to understand the behavior, I observed the same behavior where, when we use MaintenanceWorkRules (MWR) to generate Work Orders, the subject of the work order follows the format: *"Maintenance : (day) of the (month) (year)."*
>
> I was going through the internal documentation and references and found out that this is hardcoded and unfortunately, it cannot be configured or changed. This limitation restricts the customization of the work order subject.
> [...]

Hence there seems to be no way to define the subject text template directly.

In the end I created a flow to do the job

- Record-Triggered Flow
- On Create of `WorkOrder`
- Check if *IsGeneratedFromMaintenancePlan* flag on `WorkOrder` is set
- Get parent `Asset` *Asset_parent*
- Assign `WorkOrder` *Subject* via formula "Maintenance *"&{!Asset_parent.Name}&" - "&TEXT({!$Record.SuggestedMaintenanceDate})*